# Multiple images depending on mouse location when hovering over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to do an overview page on my website so that when I hover over a div on the overview page different sections of that div show different images. Essentially a slideshow but the image changes depending on where the cursor is.

I have managed to find some code that does what I want but it uses an a href to pull in the images which means if you click it, it goes to the link of the image.

Currently I just have placeholder images in but when finished each one will have specific project images in. As each div will just be one project the whole div should go to one html link and not just a specific image link of the image the user is hovering over.

All I want is the user to click  and it go to a html link and not an img link.

Here is the code I am using:

The coding savvy people out there will probably have a much better solution for what I would like to achieve, I am interested to see any better solutions.

HTML

```
     <div class="multi">
        <ul class="rotator-nav fifth clearfix">
            <li><a href="/img/FoI.jpg" onclick="return false;" class="img1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/images/card.jpg" onclick="return false;" class="img2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/images/amareal.jpg" onclick="return false;" class="img3"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/images/edeva.jpg" onclick="return false;" class="img4"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/images/amacover2.gif" onclick="return false;" class="img5"></a></li> 
        </ul>
    <div class="imgcontent">
        <ul class="rotator-icons fifth">
            <span class="img1 active"></span>
            <span class="img2"></span>
            <span class="img3"></span>
            <span class="img4"></span>
            <span class="img5"></span>
        </ul>

    <img src="/img/FoI.jpg" class="currentimg">
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.multi {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30.8%;
    height: 20%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0% 1% 2% 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.multi .imgcontent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.imgcontent img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.rotator-nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.rotator-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.rotator-nav.fourth li {
  width: 25%;
}
.rotator-nav.fifth li {
  width: 20%;
}

.rotator-nav li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom:0px solid #fff
}

.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  var $rotators = $('.multi');
  var $imglinks = $('.rotator-nav a');

  $imglinks.on('mouseenter', function(e){
    var imgclass = '.'+$(this).attr('class');
    var imglink  = $(this).attr('href');

    // update main image src
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.currentimg').attr('src',imglink);

    // update current rotator icon
    var $rotators = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.rotator-icons');

    if($rotators.children(imgclass).hasClass('active')) {
      // already active icon -- do nothing
    } else {
      // remove active class then add to new icon
      $rotators.children('span').removeClass('active');
      $rotators.children(imgclass).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: This jumped out at me- you can't have span tags directly inside <ul>, children of <ul> need to be <li> (you can then have spans inside the <li>s). I also support the request for a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could best use a data attribute for this instead (if I understand the intention correctly) :

```
var imglink  = $(this).data('image');
```

```
<div class="multi">
  <ul class="rotator-nav fifth clearfix">
    <li>
      <a data-image="/img/FoI.jpg" href="#" class="img1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-image="/images/card.jpg" href="#" class="img2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-image="/images/amareal.jpg" href="#" class="img3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-image="/images/edeva.jpg" href="#" class="img4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-image="/images/amacover2.gif" href="#" class="img5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

...
```

If you'd still like to see the image over the original div, a pseudo element could be used. Advantage there is that they are not actual DOM elements and will not register clicks :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwVoZq?editors=110)

Now it would be great if the data attribute could be directly used for the content of the pseudo element as well but that doesn't seem possible. And you can't target them with JavaScript so each image would have to be defined with `nth-of-type()` in the stylesheet additionally.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Wow, I had expected it might need some adaptation here or there. Good in one go is pretty rare. Glad I could help out and thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.parent().parent()`

Just use the parent's class to find the item.

Your `$(this).parent()` * 3 is the `$(".multi")`

So your `$rotators` can't find `.rotator-icons`,

you need to use one more parent or use siblings

And I suggest do not use class if there are no need to do one thing to lots of items.